# How to migrate to the new data router (v6.4) in React, when having provider + context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'd like to use the new [Data APIs from React Router's v6.4](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router). I'm struggling with wrapping my head around it, because I have this setup:

```js
// index.js
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter> <!-- that's an old school BrowserRouter I want to replace -->
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

And inside `App` I've got:

```js
<RootProvider>
  <PathProvider> <!-- that's an issue, as it uses `useLocation` -->
    <UserProvider> <!-- also an issue - uses something else that's part of Router -->
      <AppRoutes />
    </UserProvider>
  </PathProvider>
</RootProvider>
```

`AppRoutes` is a basic list like this:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element="{<Root />}">
    <!-- .. many more here -->
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

---

What I have tried is removing the top-level `BrowserRouter`, and switching from `<AppRoutes />` to something like this:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(AuthRoutes())); // an example

<!-- all providers wrapping it -->
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
<!-- // providers -->
```

The thing is - some of my providers rely on a `BrowserRouter` hooks (like `useLocation`, `useParams`, stuff like that). At the same time, if I replace the top level `BrowserRouter` with a `RouterProvider` (with data router) - it will try to create routes that are depending on some of the providers which are not wrapping it.

---

What's your solution to that approach? Is there a way to introduce the routes later on to the `RouterProvider`? Is there a way to use `<Routes>` somewhere nested inside while have them being a data routes?

Thanks!